# Actual behavior of DevicePolicyManager.setApplicationHidden

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

Is there anyone knows SDK well enough to tell why after making my app device-owner and executing `DevicePolicyManager.setApplicationHidden` for a list of apps I can't then find them unless I'd put `PackageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA or PackageManager.MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES)` in the query flags? (meaning just `GET_META_DATA` won't work and hidden applications would not be unhidden)
I try to find them to unhide them — but no success unless I am looking for uninstalled also.

My theory is that Android doesn't really hide them, but actually marking them uninstalled yet keeping all the data — but I didn't find any information regards it in the documentation. Wonder if someone can clarify this behavior (with source).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming is ambiguous but indeed [`setApplicationHidden`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setApplicationHidden(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) effectively uninstalls the app but keeps the APK and data in storage. If you're looking for a way to prevent use of the app without uninstalling it you can try [`setPackagesSuspended`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPackagesSuspended(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)).

You can find the source for `setApplicationHidden` in [`PackageManagerService.setApplicationHiddenSettingAsUser()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#14945) (relevant abstract below). Its logic is simple:

- `setApplicationHiddenSettingAsUser` calls `packageSetting.setHidden()` to mark the package as hidden for the user,
- other methods of `PackageManagerService` call `packageSetting.getHidden()` to decide whether the package should be returned.

Code abstract for `setApplicationHiddenSettingAsUser`:

```
@Override
public boolean setApplicationHiddenSettingAsUser(String packageName, boolean hidden,
        int userId) {
    PackageSetting pkgSetting;
    ...
    try {
        ...
        synchronized (mPackages) {
            pkgSetting = mSettings.mPackages.get(packageName);
            ...
            if (pkgSetting.getHidden(userId) != hidden) {
                pkgSetting.setHidden(hidden, userId);
                mSettings.writePackageRestrictionsLPr(userId);
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```